What is wrong with my approach of finding an indorder predecessor of a binary search tree?
void inorderPredecessor(Node* root, Node* &pre,int key){
    if(root == NULL ) return ;

    if(root -> data == key){
        inorderPredecessor(root ->left , pre , key);
    }else if(root -> data > key){
        inorderPredecessor(root -> left ,pre ,key);
    }else{
        if(pre == NULL)
            pre = root;
        else if(pre -> data > root -> data)
            pre = root;
        inorderPredecessor(root -> right , pre ,key);    
    }
}

I started this approach with the thought of,

If the node you are on is equal to target node,
call for left nodes, as they are less than target node.

If node you are on is greater than the target node,
again, call for left nodes to find the target node.

And if node you are on is less than the target node,
check the node data and the "pre" variable if it is null, then set pre equal to current node,
if not, then compare both values and the smaller one is kept.


I dry run it quite a few times, I couldn't find the mistake I was making.

Is this C or C++?

@beaker oh. got it! it was my first time on stack overflow, thx for telling me that.

@TylerH its c++

This condition is wrong:
else if(pre -> data > root -> data)

In fact, you want to improve pre, so the current root's data should actually be greater than the data of pre, not less.
Changing this operator to < will solve the issue, but you actually don't need this condition, because it is guaranteed to be true when execution gets there.
Also you can combine some of the if conditions, so to get this code:
void inorderPredecessor(Node* root, Node* &pre, int key) {
    if (!root) return;

    // No need for separate case
    if (root->data >= key) {
        inorderPredecessor(root->left, pre, key);
    } else {
        // No need for condition here
        pre = root;
        inorderPredecessor(root->right, pre, key);
    }
}

